# Nested Loops in C (needs a better title)

Tags: c, loops

I'm finishing a C project for class due tomorrow at 11pm and the last part is giving me some problems. I set up a tree on a whiteboard so that I could have the correct logic, but actually implementing it is proving a bit more difficult than I initially imagined.

The assignment for this part of the project is

> The char_game function allows the user to try to guess the value that is passed as a parameter.  The prompt (which should be exactly "letter?" will be printed each time the user is asked to type a new value.  If the user types a character that is not alphabetic, the function responds by printing the line "not alphabetic". If the user types a character that is the wrong case (upper case when a lower case was expected or vice versa), the function responds by printing the line "wrong case". If the user guesses a value that is too high (later in the alphabet)
>   the program responds with "too high", and if the
>   user guesses a value that is lower than the value of the
>   parameter, the program responds with "too low".
>   If the user has tried to guess MAX_GUESSES times, and
>   has still not guessed the value, the function
>   returns a 0 to the caller.
>   If the user guesses the correct value, the function
>   returns a 1 to the caller.
>   */int char_game(char correct_char);

The tree I made for the logic is here: [image: Tree diagram of program logic]

The function that I have created so far is as follows:

```
int char_game(char correct_char)
{
    char ch;
    int count;
    int return_num;
    for (count=0;count<=MAX_GUESSES;count++)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("letter?");
            scanf("%c", &ch);
        }
        while ((ch <= 'A' || ch >= 'z') || (ch > 'Z' && ch < 'a'));

        if ((ch < 'A') || (ch > 'Z' && ch < 'a') || (ch > 'z'))
        {
            printf("not alphabetic\n");
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

        if ((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') && (correct_char >= 'a' && correct_char <= 'z'))
        {
            printf("wrong case\n");
        }
        else if ((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') && (correct_char >= 'A' && correct_char <= 'Z'))
        {
            printf("wrong case\n");
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

        if (correct_char > ch)
        {
            printf("too low\n");
        }
        else if (correct_char < ch)
        {
            printf("too high\n");
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    }

    if (correct_char == ch)
    {
        return_num = 1;
    }
    else if (count == MAX_GUESSES);
    {
        return_num = 0;
    }
    else if (correct_char < ch)
    {
        printf("too high\n");
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

if (correct_char == ch)
{
    return_num = 1;
}
else if (count == MAX_GUESSES);
{
    return_num = 0;
}

return return_num;
}
```

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for the pretty whiteboard picture ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you indicated you're having trouble writing out the logic to implement this, I would try this approach: think about what your program needs to do according to the assignment and try to write up the steps in plain english.

For example:

1. Get a letter from the user.
2. Is the letter correct?

   - return 1 if it is.
3. Is the case wrong?

   - print some message to the user.
4. If we get to this step, we know capitalization is the same but the answer is incorrect. So check if it's lower.

   - Print something for this scenario if it is.
5. At this point it's not lower so the only possibility left is higher.

   - Print something for this scenario.
6. Do we have any more guesses left?

   - If we do jump back to step 1.
   - Otherwise proceed to next step.
7. We've exhausted all our guesses and we didn't guess correctly. So return 0.

Once you've worked out the steps and it's clear in your head take the pseudo-code written and paste it into your function as a comment. Try to implement each of the steps you've written.

If a particular step appears complicated or involved, write it as a separate function and call that. For example, you might write `Inputletter` to handle step 1. In it you can check that the user entered something sensible like a letter and it would keep prompting the user if its not. When that function returns you ***know*** the user entered a letter and not something bogus like a number or symbol.

Lastly, C provides some handy functions that you can use:

- `toupper`
- `tolower`
- `isalpha`

So your code like:

```
while ((ch <= 'A' || ch >= 'z') || (ch > 'Z' && ch < 'a'));

if ((ch < 'A') || (ch > 'Z' && ch < 'a') || (ch > 'z'))
```

turns into the much more readable:

```
while (!isalpha(ch));

if  (!isalpha(ch))
```

Comment: The caveat for the last part (`isalpha`, etc. is that teachers sometimes penalize students for using material they haven't taught yet, as they want them to solve it for themselves.

Comment: @Matthew That is a good point. In such a case, they can trivially implement their own `isalpha` function.

Comment: One hyper annoying thing with writing actually useful comments on programs is that we're using Terminal and when I scroll down it doesn't do a smooth scroll, it does a jump down the equivalent of a screen rather than a smooth line by line (hope you get what I'm saying), but this is a very good suggestion, I will start doing this.

Comment: @colle I see what you mean in that sort of environment. Note you can trim the pseudo-code down without all the verbosity. The essential idea is that you're using it to guide your thought process at a higher level while keeping your code commented in a meaningful way. When you're working out complex logic, the bigger picture is easily muddled with gory details. You can use this to help keep you on track.

Answer (score 2):

You have one too many closing curly braces `}` somewhere. In two places you have a misplaced semi-colon at the end of the following:

```
else if (count == MAX_GUESSES);
                              ^
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the semi-colon. I don't think any curly braces are the problem, as 26 % 2 != 1 ;)

Comment: @colle: Look again, the code posted does have unbalanced curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

First, break it up into functions (e.g. isWrongCase(char correct, char actual).  That will improve readability and help you find bugs.  You don't need two if statements for the wrong case one.  Remember you can have intermediate `bool` or `int` variables:

```
bool firstPart = ...;
bool secondPart = ...;
if(firstPart || secondPart)
```

This can also help you organize.

You're not using break statements right.  You don't want to break out of the loop in the else conditions, but continue to the next check.  So you don't actually need an else.

Since you have the for loop, you can just do the `MAX_GUESSES` return after the for loop.  You don't have to check the number of guesses again `(count == MAX_GUESSES)` in the body of the loop.

Comment: I don't think this is allowed in the project guidelines but it's a good idea. I can remove all the else{break;} 's?

Comment: do you think I should scratch it and start over? it seems a bit far gone. do you have any specific type of loop you think is most efficient for this application?

Comment: No, I wouldn't scrap it entirely.  The for loop is actually fine.  I don't think you need the do while loop.  Basically, that will keep prompting them until they enter a letter.  However, the letter check is already done elsewhere (with output).  As mentioned, you can also get rid of the extra MAX_GUESSES check.

Comment: Matthew, thanks a million. Eventually I waited until this afternoon and got a friend to help me out and he in fact made identical suggestions as you.